# ApsectJ is throwing exception while adding @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-transactions

We are using AOP and everything works fine, I have added @Transactional.

This is happening when i move from one method to another and i can't find any connection!! !!!!
annotation and the application is not starting and throwing exception:

```
 Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 014e b800 2699 0032 2ab4 0053 c700 202a
    0000010: bb00 2e59 b200 1412 55b7 0031 b500 53b8


    0000020: 0034 2ab4 0053 b900 3a02 0057 2ab4 0053
    0000030: 2bb6 0040 a700 0a2b b900 4401 004e 2db0
    0000040:          



at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2570)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1903)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.compiledByAjc(AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.isAspect(AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:105)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:103)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:289)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:930)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:465)
```

The only thing that cause this is when i add @Transactional on top of the Class of on top of one of the methods.. I don't have a clue.
Please update me if you need more details in order to solve this.

EDIT:

I am using JDK 1.8_05, Spring version is 4.0.3 with Instrumentation agent.
I am working with Eclipse Luna Release (4.4.0) and OS is windows 8.

The weird thing is that if i move the @Transactional annotation between 2 methods.. One of them works and the other one just make the app crash on startup..

Thanks

Comment: Which JVM and version are you using on which platform?

Comment: Please look on my edit above

Comment: Can you try to update to the latest releases of JVM, Spring and aspectj ?

Comment: I answered my question.. Thanks for trying.. This is really weird but it solved the inconsistency between methods and @transactional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long search... I found the solution for this.. Although it seems weird, I tried to update spring version and it solve the issue.. Spring version was updated from 4.0.3 to 4.1.4

Thanks for those who tried to help me :)